# include <string> gives C2275 '_To': illegal use of this type as an expression in simple c++ win32 vs 2015

Tags: visual-c++

I try to make a simple win32 empty project:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

i get following error: '_To': illegal use of this type as an expression

Answer (score 0):

You might have selected File->New->Project->Win32 project. This may cause the problem. Please create project in visual studio by selecting following options. **File->New->Project->Win32 console Application**.